# A test that returns different outputs with cypress run & cypress open using the same browser (Electron)

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

The next code always passes while running `cypress open` but never passes when running `cypress run`. In both cases we use Electron 94.
Do you have any possible idea of how that can happen?

```
cy.contains('.pack-title', statut)
  .next('div')
  .find("mat-expansion-panel-header")
  .click();
cy.get("mat-form-field")
  .find("textarea")
  .should('be.visible').and('contain', '');
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting

Comment: How can I debug from `cypress run`? cy.debug(), console.log() & cy.log() only works with `cypress open` and the test only fails when running `cypress run`

Comment: Without the error message I won't be able to help.

Comment: You can try to add some assertions on the element you are trying to click before clicking. Also, there is a default browser size for running headlessly which may fail your test as well.

Comment: use cy.wait(1000) after click()